# How to show the registration and login form in a popup in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

Hello I am trying to place the registration and login in different popup, but I don't know why when the registry modal opens it does not bring all the information that corresponds to the phtml register, i use boostrap for the modal.

[image]

As shown in the image, blue is what I lack in the modal

I am bringing the information through this line of code :

`<?php  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('persistent/customer/form/login.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>`

this line is the one that is not shown in the modal :

```
<?php $_taxvat = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_taxvat') ?>
                            <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()) : ?>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                            <?php echo $_taxvat->setTaxvat($this->getFormData()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?>
                                            <div class="validation-advice bad error" id="advice-required-entry-taxvat" style="color:red;display: none;">Por favor, introduce tu rut correcto</div>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif ?>
                        </div>
```

I also did the test outside the modal but it does not bring me all the information I need from the register.

please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to show login form fields on your popup. Tested on 1.9.3.4.

echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/form_login')
->setTemplate('customer/form/mini.login.phtml')
->toHtml();